# Error R csv: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : 'file' must be a character string or connection

Tags: r, csv

I'm struggling with an R tutorial for the package MiRLAB although I'm not sure whether the problem is related to the package's function.

I want to use the function `Pearson()`, which only accepts .csv files. I've loaded a file perfectly but when I've tried the function `Pearson()` (the same happens with MI, IDA and Lasso), this error message appeared:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
>   quote,  : 'file' must be a character string or connection

```
dataset=read.csv("ArabPrueba1.csv", sep = ";")
cause= 3:23
effect= 24:44
pearson=Pearson(dataset,cause,effect)
```

Any idea on how can I change the file or the command line so it will be recognized by the function? Might it be a problem with the csv file or something else? In the example of the tutorial the file is directly taken from the package so this approach is not covered.

Thank you in advance

Comment: i think you should use: 
pearson=Pearson("ArabPrueba1.csv",cause,effect)

Comment: When I do so the error that appears is : Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: try using a comma separated instead of semicolon

Comment: does your csv file has headers?

Comment: The ´read.csv` works fine with the semicolon, but somehow fails when using it in the function. I've also tried  `pearson = Pearson(read.csv("ArabPrueba1.csv", sep = ";"), cause, effect)` but then, the error I get is `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection`.

Comment: basically as i understand it, Pearson function uses read.table function. so you should only supply the path to your file.
try using it with different file that has comma for separator, cause maybe the function creator uses it as default separator

Comment: The file does have headers but the error keeps appearing: ´pearson = Pearson(read.csv("ArabPrueba1.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE), cause, effect)´

Comment: `"file" must be a character string or connection` meaning you should supply path to the file

Comment: you shouldn't use read.csv, its being used internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem, even if it doesn't seem a clean solution, it works. I guess the problem was that some extra "" were added to the original files when I took them to the console so I rewrite the files and re-added the recently created files to the console.

```
RNA <- read.table("RNA.csv", dec = ",", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
tRNA <- t(RNA)
write.table(tRNA, file = "tRNA_2.csv", quote = FALSE, dec = ".", sep = ",", qmethod = "escape")
tRNAt <- read.csv("tRNA_2.csv")

miRNA <- read.table("miRNA.csv", dec = ",", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
tmiRNA <- t(miRNA)
write.table(tmiRNA, file = "tmiRNAt.csv", quote = FALSE, dec = ".", sep = ",", qmethod = "escape")
tmiRNAt <- read.csv("tmiRNAt.csv")

dataset <- cbind2(x=tmiRNAt, y = tRNAt)
write.table(dataset, file = "dataset_2.csv", quote = FALSE, dec = ".", sep = ",", qmethod = "escape")

# MiRLAB:
library(miRLAB)
cause = 1:278
effect = 279:length(dataset)
ps = Pearson("dataset_2.csv", cause = cause, effect = effect)
```

I know it's not a good idea to write and read so many times but it's actually the way that it have worked better (worked at all).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

here is an example:

```
# working:
# create csv file with "," seprator
write.table(x = mtcars, file = "data.csv", sep = ",", row.names = F)
Pearson(datacsv = "data.csv", cause = 2:3, effect = 3:4)

#           cyl      disp
#disp 0.9020329 1.0000000
#hp   0.8324475 0.7909486


# not work:
# create csv file with ";" seprator
write.table(x = mtcars, file = "data1.csv", sep = " ; ", row.names = F, col.names = F)
Pearson(datacsv = "data1.csv", cause = 2:3, effect = 3:4)
```

the inner read.csv uses default seprator ","
just change your file and replace all semicolon with comma